# Minimum of two measures is no measure

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal A, \mu ), (X, \mathcal A, \nu)$ be two measure spaces.
>   Show $\lambda(A)=\min(\mu(A), \nu(A))$ is in general no measure on $(X, \mathcal A)$

It may be an easy question but I am really going crazy as I can't find a counterexample. I tried combinations of the trivial measure and counting measure but never got the desired results. Please release me from this pain.

Comment: For whatever reason I get the impression that subadditivity may fail in some cases, but I don't have any great reason why yet.

Comment: Let your space have two points, and let $\mu$ vanish on one and $\lambda$ vanish on the other. That should fail additivity I think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's use $X = \{x_{1}, x_{2}\}$, i.e., a set consisting of just two points, ${\cal A}$ = the set of all (four:) subsets of $X$, and the measures defined by the following:
$$
\mu(\{x_{1}\}) = 1, \quad \mu(\{x_{2}\}) = 0,
$$
$$
\nu(\{x_{1}\}) = 0, \quad \nu(\{x_{2}\}) = 1.
$$

Now, check whether additivity holds: does
$$
\lambda(\{x_{1}, x_{2}\})
$$
equal
$$
\lambda(\{x_{1}\}) + \lambda(\{x_{2}\})?
$$